# Matplotlib: How to plot a small rectangle filled with a colormap as a legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, colormap

Instead of a plotting a colorbar next to my plot, I want to plot a small rectangle filled with the colormap as a legend.

I already can plot a small rectangle filled with any color, by doing the following trick:

```
axis0, = myax.plot([], linewidth=10, color='r')

axis =[axis0]
legend=['mytext']

plt.legend(axis,
           legend)
```

Can I do the same with a colormap? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To my knowledge, there is no way of doing this other than by creating the rectangle and legend from scratch. Here is one approach (based mainly on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57791790/14148248)):

```
import numpy as np                                    # v 1.19.2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                       # v 3.3.2
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

rng = np.random.default_rng(seed=1)

ncmaps = 5     # number of colormaps to draw for illustration
ncolors = 100  # number high enough to draw a smooth gradient for each colormap

# Create random list of colormaps and extract list of colors to 
# draw the gradient of each colormap
cmaps_names = list(rng.choice(plt.colormaps(), size=ncmaps))
cmaps = [plt.cm.get_cmap(name) for name in cmaps_names]
cmaps_gradients = [cmap(np.linspace(0, 1, ncolors)) for cmap in cmaps]
cmaps_dict = dict(zip(cmaps_names, cmaps_gradients))

# Create a list of lists of patches representing the gradient of each colormap
patches_cmaps_gradients = []
for cmap_name, cmap_colors in cmaps_dict.items():
    cmap_gradient = [patches.Patch(facecolor=c, edgecolor=c, label=cmap_name)
                     for c in cmap_colors]
    patches_cmaps_gradients.append(cmap_gradient)

# Create custom legend (with a large fontsize to better illustrate the result)
plt.legend(handles=patches_cmaps_gradients, labels=cmaps_names, fontsize=20,
           handler_map={list: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None, pad=0)})

plt.show()
```

[image: legend_colormap]

If you plan on doing this for multiple plots, you may want to create a [custom legend handler](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html#implementing-a-custom-legend-handler) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55501861/14148248). You may also want to consider other ways of displaying the colorbar, such as in the examples shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64432950/14148248) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44868640/14148248) and [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/demo_colorbar_with_inset_locator.html).

Documentation: [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html)

Comment: Thank you @Patrick FitzGerald, I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

In my [CMasher](https://github.com/1313e/CMasher) package, I implemented a function called `set_cmap_legend_entry()` that does exactly this for you.
You can give it a plot element and a label, and it will automatically create a colormap legend entry for it, like for the image shown below (see [here](https://cmasher.readthedocs.io/user/usage.html#legend-entries) for the documentation on this):

[image]