# matplotlib.patches: One patch with mulitple colors

Tags: python, matplotlib

I can create a custom legend with a color per category this way:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

#one color per patch
#define class and colors
colors = ['#01FF4F', '#FFEB00', '#FF01D7', '#5600CC']
categories = ['A','B','C','D']
#create dict
legend_dict=dict(zip(categories,colors))
#create patches
patchList = []
for key in legend_dict:
        data_key = mpatches.Patch(color=legend_dict[key], label=key)
        patchList.append(data_key)

#plotting
plt.gca()
plt.legend(handles=patchList,ncol=len(categories), fontsize='small')
plt.show()
```

Now I want to create a legend, where each patch is made up of n colors.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

 #multiple colors per patch
 colors = [['#01FF4F','#01FF6F'], ['#FFEB00','#FFEB00'], ['#FF01D7','#FF01D7','#FF01D7'], ['#5600CC']]
 categories = ['A','B','C','D']
 #create dict
 legend_dict=dict(zip(categories,colors))
 print(legend_dict)
```

The patch for category A should have the colors '#01FF4F'and '#01FF6F'. For category B it's '#FFEB00' and '#FFEB00' and so on.

Comment: Yes, a patch has a single color (or two if you count face- and edge-color separately). I do have slight problems understanding the desired outcome. I.e. what does a a patch that is made up of n colors supposed to look like?

Comment: The desired outcome is a patch, which is for example: 1/3 blue 1/3red and 1/3green

Comment: Oh, that means 3 patches, really.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about that too. But it seems like rather extensive solution due individual patch creation and positioning.
So I was wondering if there's a way to make it work with a list of colors per label.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi-color Legend Entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908982/multi-color-legend-entry)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Patches have a facecolor and an edgecolor. So you can colorize those differently, like

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

#one color per patch
#define class and colors
 #multiple colors per patch
colors = [['#01FF4F','#00FFff'], 
           ['#FFEB00','#FFFF00'], 
            ['#FF01D7','#FF00aa'], 
             ['#5600CC','#FF00EE']]
categories = ['A','B','C','D']
#create dict
legend_dict=dict(zip(categories,colors))
#create patches
patchList = []
for key in legend_dict:
        data_key = mpatches.Patch(facecolor=legend_dict[key][0], 
                                  edgecolor=legend_dict[key][1], label=key)
        patchList.append(data_key)

#plotting
plt.gca()
plt.legend(handles=patchList,ncol=len(categories), fontsize='small')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Or if you really want different patches of different color you can create tuples of those patches and supply them to the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple

#one color per patch
#define class and colors
 #multiple colors per patch
colors = [['#01FF4F','#00FFff'], 
           ['#FFEB00','#FFFF00'], 
            ['#FF01D7','#FF00aa'], 
             ['#5600CC','#FF00EE']]
categories = ['A','B','C','D']
#create dict
legend_dict=dict(zip(categories,colors))
#create patches
patchList = []
for cat, col in legend_dict.items():
    patchList.append([mpatches.Patch(facecolor=c, label=cat) for c in col])


plt.gca()
plt.legend(handles=patchList, labels=categories, ncol=len(categories), fontsize='small',
           handler_map = {list: HandlerTuple(None)})

plt.show()
```

[image]